# How do I change the privileges for MySQL user that is already created?

Tags: mysql

I understand how to create a new user with privileges, but what is the correct way to change privileges for users that are already created?

We are running a DB audit and some of the users have way more access then is needed. Plus I don't know the passwords for most of these MySQL users, so I don't want to delete them and create new ones.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

To list users:

```
select user,host from mysql.user;
```

To show privileges:

```
show grants for 'user'@'host';
```

To change privileges, first revoke.  Such as:

```
revoke all privileges on *.* from 'user'@'host';
```

Then grant the appropriate privileges as desired:

```
grant SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON `db`.* TO 'user'@'host';
```

Finally, flush:

```
flush privileges;
```

The MySQL documentation is excellent:

- [Access Control and Account Management](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/access-control.html)

Comment: Well without revoke, it will be dublicates privileges;

Comment: mysql documentation is near unreadable, this answer is much better

Comment: I think (revoke all privileges on *.* from 'user'@'host'; )
should be (revoke all on *.* from 'user'@'host';) Thanks,

Comment: this answer is plain wrong "flush privileges" does not apply to privileges set with grant. the above process results in the user having no privilege at all between the moment the revoke and the grant queries are run, and additionally flushing the grants cache for no reason __ this would work if you perform regular queries against the mysql.user table rather than using grants and if the server does not crash or stop between the queries.

Comment: How can it be done without leaving the user with no privileges during the gap?

Answer (score 0):

without downtime you can do this (example for granting ALTER command):

```
UPDATE mysql.db
set Alter_priv='Y'
WHERE User='USER'
```

for any other privilege, see current user privileges and right columns to change:

```
SELECT *
FROM mysql.db
WHERE User='USER'
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use ansible [mysql_user](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/mysql/mysql_user_module.html) module.
It maintains the user permissions without revoking everything.
Grant a few permissions in `test` db on `testtable` table:
`playbook.yaml` content:

```
---
- name:
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
  tasks:
  - name: Test user
    community.mysql.mysql_user:
      name: testuser
      password: testpassword
      priv:
        'test.testtable': SELECT,INSERT,ALTER
      login_host: 127.0.0.1
      login_user: root
      login_password: root
      state: present
```

Run `ansible-playbook playbook.yaml`
Then revoke `ALTER` by removing from `priv`:

```
'test.testtable': SELECT,INSERT
```

run again `ansible-playbook playbook.yaml`
I checked mysql logs to make sure it does not revoke all, before grant:

```
2022-10-10T14:34:54.911222Z      1632 Query     SHOW GRANTS FOR 'testuser'@'localhost'
2022-10-10T14:34:54.911797Z      1632 Query     REVOKE ALTER ON `test`.`testtable` FROM 'testuser'@'localhost'
2022-10-10T14:34:54.947049Z      1632 Query     FLUSH PRIVILEGES
2022-10-10T14:34:54.951583Z      1632 Query     SHOW GRANTS FOR 'testuser'@'localhost'
```