# Access to MySQL server via VirtualBox

Tags: mysql, virtualbox

I am trying to get MySQL server (which is inside VM) to respond to client (which is on the host machine). All methods return same:

```
Host '10.0.2.2' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

I have ensured proper port forwardind. I also ensured, that in `my.cnf` I have folowing lines:

```
skip-external-locking
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

This did not work to me. I also tried to play a bit as folowing:

```
bind-address = 10.0.2.2
```

But this also did not work to me - server just could not start.

Any ideas, where I am wrong?

**UPDATE.** I did not check privilegies for `root@%` as in [How do I change the privileges for MySQL user that is already created?](https://serverfault.com/questions/115950/how-do-i-change-the-privileges-for-mysql-user-that-is-already-created)

**SOLVED.**

Comment: What user accounts have you created within MySQL?

Comment: My accout is `root:root`. I doubt that problem is in logins, otherwise error message would state something lile `Access denied for root@10.0.2.2` or something.

Comment: @ShaneMadden Sorry. You were pretty right. The thing was in privilegies for `root@%`. Pretty my fault.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The root account's localhost-only in the vast majority of default installations, are you certain you've allowed it to log in from the other system?  From the [MySQL reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/access-denied.html):

> it means that there is no row in the user table with a Host value that matches the client host

So, there's no `%` or `10.0.2.2` in the `Host` column at all.  Check your current config:

```
select user,host from mysql.user where user='root';
```

You likely want to create a new root entry with the same password as you have now.

```
create user 'root'@'10.0.2.2' identified by 'yourpassword';
grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'10.0.2.2' with grant option;
flush privileges;
```

Comment: Yep. Thank you. I also solved it just a moment ago as you stated here. That was exact my problem.

Comment: Shane's answer is correct and can be run in a single command, helpful if you are using something like an Ansible script/Vagrant to automate: `mysql -e "create user 'root'@'10.0.2.2' identified by 'yourpassword'; grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'10.0.2.2' with grant option; flush privileges;"`