# How do I modify an existing user's permissions without downtime on MySQL/MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

We have an existing database user in our MariaDB 10.3 instance. We'd like to grant the user a couple of extra permissions, without any interruption to service.

I understand from the helpful answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/115950/how-do-i-change-the-privileges-for-mysql-user-that-is-already-created) the basic process, but I'm concerned that between the execution of the `REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES...` command and the `GRANT ...` command that the user will not have any access to the database. Is this correct? If so, is there a good way around this, other than creating a new user with a different username and migrating the application code to use this new user instead?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you trying to change the privileges of a _logged in_ user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you modify the mysql database directely with `UPDATE` (in *user* and *db* tables), then use `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` command, you will not revoke anything. So no user interruption...

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Privileges are not looked at except during login.  That is, whatever you do to the grant tables won't take effect until the user logs out and logs back in.

Comment: No, I didn't need to change for an already logged in user. This scenario is a web application where the database user logs in for each web request (so many times per second) but only stays logged in for the duration of the page load (so usually under a second). I simply needed a solution which meant I could change the permissions going forward (prior to deployment of an update which needed the extra permissions), but without breaking the many logins per second which were happening during this time. The solution from @Dom did the trick. Thanks.